# If the Feign Death spell is cast on a creature, do they register as magical if the Detect Magic spell is cast to inspect them?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic

The description of the [*feign death*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feign-death) spell (PHB, p. 240) says:

> For the spell’s duration, or until you use an action to touch the target and dismiss the spell, the target appears dead to all outward inspection and to spells used to determine the target’s status.

To me, using *detect magic* on a corpse to see if it is still under a spell is actually using a spell to determine the target's status, since [when a creature dies, all spell effects requiring concentration on it are ended](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/763519890296668162) — thus, using *detect magic* to determine whether the creature is still alive (under a magic spell effect) or not (an inanimate object, a corpse).  So the *feign death* spell would effectively prevent the magical aura from being detected by the *detect magic* spell.

Am I incorrect in this determination?

RAW please, no opinions or interpretations.

Comment: If you want "RAW, no opinions or interpretations" then you can read the rules for yourself, and you've done that. Every possible answer to this question is an interpretation.

Comment: @markwells Okay but you (hopefully) know what they meant. Literally everything requires interpretation, RAW is just a *more specific way of interpretating*

Comment: The tweet you've linked says that any concentration spells end when the *caster* dies, not the *target*. Which makes sense, because you can't concentrate on something when you're dead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Yes, they register as magical

Firstly, you are wrong when you say all spell effects on a creature vanish when it dies. If you need proof then check out the [*finger of death*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Finger%20of%20Death#content) spell.

Secondly, *detect magic* is designed to detect active magic. It isn't designed to detect a creature's status as alive or dead. As such, the clause in the *feign death* spell is irrelevant, and an aura of magic will be detected on the target creature.

Comment: Finger of death does not indicate that the zombie that rises after the creature is dead is magic in any sort of way.  It will not produce a magical aura.  A zombie is a zombie and unless stated in the spell description or rule, it it not a magical.  Can you provide supporting evidence where you identified that finger of death keeps the corpse with a magical aura ?

Comment: can you provide a few example of what kind of spells are used to detect creature status, there does not seem to be that many.. It seems feign death is a pretty useless spells if it can be foiled that easily is it not ?

Comment: @KilrathiSly An enemy has to actively expend a lvl 1 spell to use Detect Magic. It is unlikely that many people go around Detect Magic'ing every single corpse they see.

Comment: @KilrathiSly Active spells can be detected by Detect Magic. There is no flavor text in 5e "the presence of magic" literally means any magic present.

Comment: @jgn: Note that *detect magic* is a ritual; spell slot expenditure is not always necessary, though it will take more time to cast in that case. (...Though I'm not sure if there are rules on whether monsters/NPCs can ritual-cast, in the absence of a Spellcasting feature that says they can.)

Comment: @V2Blast True, but taking 10 minutes is still restrictive in most circumstances. Also note that yeah you do need a feature to ritual cast.

Comment: @KilrathiSly: if the existence of Feign Death causes your opponents to waste their time and spell slots casting Detect Magic on every corpse they pass, I wouldn't say it's useless. You don't even have to cast it for it to be useful, you just need your opponent to suspect you know it. And if it *doesn't* cause them to do that, then you can use Feign Death to sneak someone into their... um... mortuary? I think Feign Death just has the same limitation as any deception-type spell which is detectable with the "right" detection spell and not with the "wrong" one.

Comment: @KilrathiSly Detect magic won't show a zombie as being magical. But finger of death makes a creature killed with it turn into a zombie at the start of your next turn. Which means that there is a one round gap between when it dies, and is simply a corpse, and when it rises up as a zombie. During that time the magical effect of the spell is still in effect on the corpse.

Comment: OK.  so if someone wants to pass a 'live' character as a corpse.. in order to really be sure a wise guy sorcerer that would cast detect magic on it and not see through the ruse would be to add a 'non-detection' spell on it... that would prevent the magic from registering by the detect magic.  right ?

Comment: @Allan Mills :  PHB states that finger of death as being instantaneous duration,  In the instantaneous spell description on effect (PHB 203) it indiicates that the spell is active only mere instant for the effet to happen, why would this particular spell effect lingers for longer than that ?

Comment: @KilrathiSly I'm not sure about non-detection. It would prevent the "corpse" from being detected, but it isn't designed to prevent the spell from being detected AFAIK. An instantaneous duration doesn't mean the spell is over an done with after an instant. Take a look at feeblemind. It has an instantaneous duration but the text description makes it clear that the spell remains in effect until it is removed by magic or the target passes their saving throw.

Comment: I see this similar as a fireball cast on a pile of wood.   the wood would still burn afterwards.  but not register as magic as the fire is a byproduct of the spell, not the spell itself.  finger of death is similar to me,  you die and will become an undead next turn.  but still not register as magical for that turn. With feeblemind, it is specifically indicated that the spell will continue being active until the creature saves itself in the description. so for feeblemind yes the creature will register as magical.

Answer (score 8):

## The *feign death* target will appear magical

*Detect magic* says

> you sense the presence of magic within 30 feet of you. If you sense magic in this way, you can use your action to see a faint aura around any visible creature or object in the area that bears magic, and you learn its school of magic, if any.

*Detect magic* would not directly tell you that the body is alive and under the effects of a *feign death* spell. Rather, it will only tell you that the body is under the effect of a necromancy spell or other magical effect of the school of necromancy. *Detect magic* works on both objects and creatures. Furthermore, the clause in *feign death* does not make any provision for concealing itself, only the status of the body. Because the information provided by *detect magic* is non-specific and does not directly tell you about whether the body is dead or alive, *detect magic* would function normally.

But what conclusions can be drawn when you detect necromancy magic on a body? That the body is under *feign death* is definitely one possibility. A greater possibility is that the body is an undead creature of some kind, or soon to be undead\$^1\$. It could also be under *gentle repose*, although *gentle repose* also requires a copper piece laid on each eye so that would be a clue. It could also be *magic jar* or *astral projection*, although the body is catatonic rather than dead in those cases so proper inspection would reveal the body to not be dead. Those are all the necromancy spells from [D&DBeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/school/necromancy?sort=-spell-duration) which you could find on a body. There could also be other magical effects, such as from special abilities or magic items or homebrew.

To summarise, if you detect necromancy on an apparently-dead body, the body can be alive (as per *feign death*), dead (as per *gentle repose*) or undead (as per *danse macabre* or assumptions about magic\$^1\$). Since all three are possible, *detect magic* does not definitively tell you the body is not dead, so *feign death* should not inhibit *detect magic*.

If you suspect that you need to fool *detect magic*, there are a few things you could do. You could place some copper coins over the target's eyes to make them appear to be under the effects of *gentle repose* - which definitely applies to corpses. Or you can use the False Aura option of *Nystul's Magic Aura* to hide the magic.

Weakness to *detect magic* aside, *feign death* has other uses. It can be used to suspend the effects of poison and disease. And not everyone has *detect magic* available or always active, so *feign death* is far from useless.

---

1. The typical spells for creating undead, *animate dead* and *create undead*, have a duration of instantaneous. This means that, very strictly speaking, a creature created by *animate dead* should not show as magical under *detect magic*. It is still possible to get zombies which detect as magical using *danse macabre*, because it has a duration of 1 hour. Also, even if *animate dead* should not strictly trigger *detect magic*, most adventurers and NPCs would likely assume that a corpse radiating necromancy magic must be undead. Further, in real play, I have found it quite common that undead will *detect* as having an aura of necromancy regardless of minutiae in the definitions of what is 'magical'.